# "I am closing a core ClientSessionFactory you left open." when memory is full

Tags: java, openshift, wildfly

I have a RESTFUL service on Openshift Wildfly 10 that throws the following exception when memory is full.  I have *0* (no) dependencies and I am not even using JMS.  It's using a simple HashMap "dao" with about 4 items in it.

I cannot find a leak and Findbugs finds nothing.  Any ideas?

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Finalizer) AMQ212008: I am closing a core ClientSessionFactory you left open. Please make sure you close all ClientSessionFactories explicitly before letting them go out of scope! 22,836,318: 
java.lang.Exception
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:170)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:756)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.recovery.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.connect(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.java:314)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.recovery.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.java:239)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.recovery.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.recover(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapper.java:69)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.service.extensions.xa.ActiveMQXAResourceWrapperImpl.recover(ActiveMQXAResourceWrapperImpl.java:106)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecoveryFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:550)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:190)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:747)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:375)
```

Comment: Given that WildFly 10 is in prerelease it's possible that you have found a bug that should be reported...

Answer (score 0):

WildFly 10, by itself, will consume most if not all of the memory allocated on a small gear.  If you would like to run it on OpenShift Online, you would probably need to run at least a medium, if not a large gear.  You can follow these directions to check your memory limit violations on your gear: https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues

You could also try following these instructions to change the amount of memory allocated to the JVM: https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-jvm-memory.html

But be aware that if you are also running a database on that gear, you will still run into memory issues.